# NSURLConnection Error Code -1100

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to load content into UIWebView, and when testing in the simulator all I get is a white screen and the following error in the console:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

Can anybody help? My current Swift Code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;         
        webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;  

        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www/index", ofType: "html")!)))  

        let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView  
        statusBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear  

    }  
}
```

Just to clarify, this code usual works for me, but I can't find anything online relating to error -1100.
Many thanks.

Comment: `URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www/index", ofType: "html")` Why? Just use `Bundle.url(forResource:withExtension:)`.

Answer (score 8):

`-1100` means `NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`. And you are accessing a local file, print the URL's `absoluteString` to check the path is good for that file.

Comment: Hello. Yes I tested it, and works fine on browser. I am running the files locally by adding to my Xcode project. This method works with other html packages but not this one for some reason. Thanks for highlighting what the error code means though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using local file. I updated the answer for another check.

Answer (score 1):

For mine, The network didn't connected properly. Then I turned on my data connection after that I solved it.

Answer (score -3):

Short description for all `NSURLRequest` error codes: [URL Loading System Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes)

- NSURLErrorUnknown

Returned when the URL Loading system encounters an error that it cannot interpret.

- NSURLErrorCancelled

Returned when an asynchronous load is canceled.

- NSURLErrorBadURL

Returned when a URL is sufficiently malformed that a URL request cannot be initiated

- NSURLErrorTimedOut

Returned when an asynchronous operation times out.

- NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL

Returned when a properly formed URL cannot be handled by the framework.

- NSURLErrorCannotFindHost

Returned when the host name for a URL cannot be resolved.

- NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost

Returned when an attempt to connect to a host has failed.

- NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum

Returned when the length of the resource data exceeds the maximum allowed.

- NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost

Returned when a client or server connection is severed in the middle of an in-progress load.

- NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed

See 
NSURLErrorCannotFindHost

- NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects

Returned when a redirect loop is detected or when the threshold for number of allowable redirects has been exceeded (currently 16).

- NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable

Returned when a requested resource cannot be retrieved.

- NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet

Returned when a network resource was requested, but an internet connection is not established and cannot be established automatically, either through a lack of connectivity, or by the user's choice not to make a network connection automatically.

- NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation

Returned when a redirect is specified by way of server response code, but the server does not accompany this code with a redirect URL.

- NSURLErrorBadServerResponse

Returned when the URL Loading system receives bad data from the server.

- NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication

Returned when an asynchronous request for authentication is cancelled by the user.

- NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired

Returned when authentication is required to access a resource.

- NSURLErrorZeroByteResource

Returned when a server reports that a URL has a non-zero content length, but terminates the network connection “gracefully” without sending any data.

- NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData

Returned when content data received during an NSURLConnection request cannot be decoded for a known content encoding.

- NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData

Returned when content data received during an NSURLConnection request has an unknown content encoding.

- NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse

Returned when a response to an NSURLConnection request cannot be parsed.

- NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff

Returned when a connection would require activating a data context while roaming, but international roaming is disabled.

- NSURLErrorCallIsActive

Returned when a connection is attempted while a phone call is active on a network that does not support simultaneous phone and data communication (EDGE or GPRS).

- NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed

Returned when the cellular network disallows a connection.

- NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted

Returned when a body stream is needed but the client does not provide one. This impacts clients on iOS that send a POST request using a body stream but do not implement the NSURLConnection delegate method connection:needNewBodyStream.

- NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist

Returned when a file does not exist.

- NSURLErrorFileIsDirectory

Returned when a request for an FTP file results in the server responding that the file is not a plain file, but a directory.

- NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile

Returned when a resource cannot be read due to insufficient permissions.

- NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed

Returned when an attempt to establish a secure connection fails for reasons which cannot be expressed more specifically.

- NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate

Returned when a server certificate has a date which indicates it has expired, or is not yet valid.

- NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted

Returned when a server certificate is signed by a root server which is not trusted.

- NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasUnknownRoot

Returned when a server certificate is not signed by any root server.

- NSURLErrorServerCertificateNotYetValid

Returned when a server certificate is not yet valid.

- NSURLErrorClientCertificateRejected

Returned when a server certificate is rejected.

- NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired

Returned when a client certificate is required to authenticate an SSL connection during an NSURLConnection request.

- NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork

Returned when a specific request to load an item only from the cache cannot be satisfied.

- NSURLErrorCannotCreateFile

Returned when NSURLDownload object was unable to create the downloaded file on disk due to a I/O failure.

- NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile

Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to open the downloaded file on disk.

- NSURLErrorCannotCloseFile

Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to close the downloaded file on disk.

- NSURLErrorCannotWriteToFile

Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to write to the downloaded file on disk.

- NSURLErrorCannotRemoveFile

Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to remove a downloaded file from disk.

- NSURLErrorCannotMoveFile

Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to move a downloaded file on disk.

- NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream

Returned when NSURLDownload failed to decode an encoded file during the download.

- NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedToComplete

Returned when NSURLDownload failed to decode an encoded file after downloading.

- NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection
- NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionInUseByAnotherProcess
- NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer
- NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionWasDisconnected
- NSURLErrorFileOutsideSafeArea